# Google timezone api showing wrong daylight saving offset

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, timezone, google-api

So now London is having +1 hour daylight saving. I'm requesting to Google timezone api to request the london timezone. But it's not giving me the right time.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=51.5072,-0.1275&timestamp=1331766000&key=[API_KEY]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=51.5072,-0.1275&timestamp=1331766000&key=AIzaSyBgx7dDMktRN_ziLp70t6LNDC9sY70Pflo)

This giving me result as

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : 0,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "Europe/London",
   "timeZoneName" : "Greenwich Mean Time"
}
```

Shouldn't it give me dstOffset of 3600??

I followed this guideline [Timezone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

What's wrong? How can I get the timezone with the daylight saving on or off?

Comment: Exactly, I want that with coordinates. Can google api give me that! doesn't the summer time regarded as daylight saving? it was described in the guideline that daylight saving time will be given in `dstoffset` @RobG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp you provided (1331766000) corresponds to 14 Mar 2012 23:00:00 GMT, which probably wasn't a time when daylight saving applied (it starts on the last Sunday in March).

The value should be seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, which you can get as `Date.now()/1000` since javascript time values are milliseconds since the same epoch. For 2014-06-24T13:15:34.000Z the timestamp is 1403615734. If that is used, you'll get:

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 3600,
   "rawOffset" : 0,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "Europe/London",
   "timeZoneName" : "British Summer Time"
}
```